# use increment inside lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda

I have a block like this

```
int i = 0;
shaders.forEach((WrappedShader shader) -> 
{
    int shader_id = glCreateShader(shader.getShader_type());
    glShaderSource(shader_id, shader.getShader_source());
    glCompileShader(shader_id);
    glAttachShader(shader_program, shader_id);
    shader_ids[i++] = shader_id;
});
```

But how to have increment inside lambda? Currently it asks to set the variable `i` as final and do not change it.

I know I can rewrite it to  `for` loop but I'd like to use lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, for functional program you should have pure functions with *no* side effects.  In this case, you have side effects but you could do is

```
int[] sharedIds = shaders.stream().mapToInt((WrappedShader shader) -> {
            int shader_id = glCreateShader(shader.getShader_type());
            glShaderSource(shader_id, shader.getShader_source());
            glCompileShader(shader_id);
            glAttachShader(shader_program, shader_id);
            return shared_id;
      }).toArray();
```

Comment: Oh! Did not thought about creating enumerable as a result of lamba. Completely forgot about it.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, let me also mention that you can circumvent Java's insistence on `i` being final by declaring an `int[] i = new int[1]` and using `i[0]` instead of `i`. But it's very hacky.  Peter's answer is best.

Comment: @user1432980 it's what you should really be doing all the time.  The `forEach` is more for non-functional programming.

Comment: @MikeNakis I think you mean `int[] i = new int[1];` or `int[] i = { 0 };` and yes I have used this but never happily. ;)